# Can you see what is in memcached?

Tags: php, memcached, ubuntu-10.10, libmemcache

I'm using memcached extension in a PHP5 application. We're running a LAMP stack on Ubuntu Maverick (10.10). We're using memcached for a series of things, one of which is persisting user session among multiple applications.

My question is, is there a utility or UI to see what is inside a memcached server?

This would be an invaluable tool during development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always try Harun Yayli's [memcache.php](http://livebookmark.net/journal/2008/05/21/memcachephp-stats-like-apcphp/) or [this variation](http://artur.ejsmont.org/blog/content/first-version-of-memcache-stats-script-based-on-memcachephp) on memcache.php

Answer (score 0):

May be [FastoNoSQL](http://fastonosql.com) will be interesting for you.

[image]